# Read Word document and convert to PDF

Tags: powershell, pdf

I have thousands of word documents in a folder. My boss want me to convert all these files to PDF. I have found a solution to this, but I need to find a specific word in the document and then use the following row as the converted file name.

For example, I have `test1.doc` and I need to find the string `"rule1` (begins with double quotes) and then read 4 words after the string `rule1`, and then use these 4 words as filename for converted file in PDF. More clear, if I have `test1.doc` and in `test1.doc` there is the string `"rule1 word1 word2 word3 word4 ...`, I want to convert `test1.doc` to  `word1 word2 word3 word4.pdf` in bulk.

I found this script, but I don't know how to modify it. This script just converts all files with the same name to PDF.

```
$wdFormatPDF = 17
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $false
$folderpath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\*"
$fileTypes = "*.docx","*doc"
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Include $fileTypes | ForEach-Object {
  $path =  ($_.fullname).Substring(0, ($_.FullName).LastIndexOf("."))
  "Converting $path to pdf ..."
  $doc = $word.Documents.Open($_.FullName)
  $doc.SaveAs([ref]$path, [ref]$wdFormatPDF)
  $doc.Close()
}
$word.Quit()
```

Comment: Can you take one of your source files and put it up on PasteBin, then link it here?  We need a source file to come up with an approach.

Comment: it is just a word document,and i cant share it here because there are personal informations.

Comment: ...sanitize the document first?  If you want help, give us something to work with, dude!

Comment: I think you should be able to add a filter to the Get-ChildItem. As a first pass this could convert the document to text and search for the marker you need. The filter can return true for if the "rule1 marker exists and could set a variable with the other information. I know this is a somewhat clunky solution but it should work in principle.

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to get what you want using ComObjects in powershell:

[Powershell search matching string in word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169043/powershell-search-matching-string-in-word-document)