# Looking for people's names in a document with RegEx and Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a list of word documents, I have to search through.

Usually the document will be anonymised so that a forename and surname is replaced with a single character.

The task is to spot where the document has not been anonymised and someone's name is in the text.

For example, this text IS acceptable :
Mr X experienced an issue.

This text is also acceptable :
Mr and Mrs Y experienced an issue.

This text however is NOT acceptable :
Mr Jones experienced an issue.
or this ..
Mr and Mrs Jones experienced an issue.

I think I can obtain a list of possible titles (Mr, Mrs, Doctor etc)

So I would like to contstruct a RegEx expression that will capture the occurrence of TITLE followed by TWO or more alpha characters.

I am using Powershell Select-String applet, which supports RegEx.
So far I have this script :

```
$Search = "Mr[ ][A-Z][A-Z]"
$aryfiles = Get-Content "K:\Echo Maintenance\Scripts\SORDocSearch\filelist.csv"
Foreach ($file in $aryfiles) {

    If (Get-Content $file | Select-String -Pattern $Search) {
        $file
        Get-Content $file | Select-String -Pattern $Search 
    }
}
```

It is the RegEx expression "Mr[ ][A-Z][A-Z]" I need help with as unfortunately this matches Mr and Mrs X, the 'and' word is being interpreted as a name.

Comment: Try it like this `\bMr (?:and Mrs )?[A-Z]\w+` https://regex101.com/r/a19JNz/1 or `\bMr (?:and Mrs )?[A-Z][a-z]\w*`

Comment: You could do `\b(?:Mrs?(?: and Mrs?)?|Doctor) [A-Z][A-Za-z]+\b`

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to work perfectly in the regex link you gave.  For some reason when the text is comming from a Word (.doc) file it is giving some false positives.

Comment: @RichardBriggs What are the false positives?

Comment: Thext in the file is clean - I am thinking it is the Word format that is messing with it. This looks like a more Word friendly way of seaching https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169043/powershell-search-matching-string-in-word-document

Comment: So I am try to get that example to work with a pattern match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a match with 2 alpha characters a-z you might try 2 character classes with an optional non capturing group.

```
\bMr (?:and Mrs )?[A-Z][a-z]\w*
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbMr+%28%3f%3aand+Mrs+%29%3f%5bA-Z%5d%5ba-z%5d%5cw*&i=For+example%2c+this+text+IS+acceptable+%3a+Mr+X+experienced+an+issue.%0d%0a%0d%0aThis+text+is+also+acceptable+%3a+Mr+and+Mrs+Y+experienced+an+issue.%0d%0a%0d%0aThis+text+however+is+NOT+acceptable+%3a+Mr+Jones+experienced+an+issue.+or+this+..+Mr+and+Mrs+Jones+experienced+an+issue.%0d%0a%0d%0a)

For the titles you can use an alternation to match the different options `(?:Mrs?|Doctor)`

---

Or for a broader match of characters matching an uppercase letter and 1+ times any kind of letter:

```
\bMr (?:and Mrs )?\p{Lu}\p{L}+
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbMr+%28%3f%3aand+Mrs+%29%3f%5cp%7bLu%7d%5cp%7bL%7d%2b&i=For+example%2c+this+text+IS+acceptable+%3a+Mr+X+experienced+an+issue.%0d%0a%0d%0aThis+text+is+also+acceptable+%3a+Mr+and+Mrs+Y+experienced+an+issue.%0d%0a%0d%0aThis+text+however+is+NOT+acceptable+%3a+Mr+Jones+experienced+an+issue.+or+this+..+Mr+and+Mrs+Jones+experienced+an+issue.%0d%0a%0d%0a)

Comment: Nicely done; note that PowerShell's regexes are case-_insensitive_ by default, so in the context of the OP's command the `-CaseSensitive` switch would have to be added to the `Select-String` calls.