# Powershell Help, Need to search for pattern/string and copy to new destination

Tags: powershell

I need Help to search a Network Share for 30+ Keywords and then to copy them to a new location...
I need to search for all type of docs... txt, doc, docx, pdfs, xls, xlsx, etc...
I have a CSV file of Keywords... the header is called Words
FYI - In the CSV file I have each word is not in quotes and some lines does have two words (do they need quotes? a few have a wildcard  hous* (for houses, house, housing, etc..) does that need quotes?
example

street

1234 Elm St

Hous*

Do they need to be in Quotes?

It will wont search sub directories

This is what I have...

```
$CSV = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Username\Documents\book1.csv"

foreach ($Words in $CSV)
{
    Get-ChildItem \\Server\Groups$\HR-Dept -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern '$Words' -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Testing"
}
```

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: `gci |Select-String` seems OK with XLSX files, at least from my testing

Comment: NB: `gci |Select-String` seems OK with XLSX files on one W10 machine - further testing on Server 2016 with Office 2016 did not find strings inside XLSX files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're intending to search by file name rather than content, `-filter` does the job quite efficiently.

```
$CSV = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Username\Documents\book1.csv"

foreach ($Words in $CSV) {
    # remove any extra "*" to avoid duplication later
    $words = $words -replace "*"
    # use -File to exclude directories from match. NB: PS version-dependent
    Get-ChildItem \\Server\Groups$\HR-Dept -filter *$words* -Recurse -File | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Testing"
}
```

Spaces in your `$words` should be fine if your file names will have the same words and spaces.

I recommend trying the `gci` part first to see if you get the appropriate list of files before pipelining it to the `Copy-Item`. I haven't tested with a file path that includes a `$`, so that might be a consideration.

Comment: I do need to search the contents of the files.... I also need to search subfolders also....  I did get this error The regular expression pattern * is not valid.
At line:5 char:5
+     $words = $words -replace "*"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                            Now I'm trying to troubleshoot the main line.. this is what I have                                            Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\david.bowyer\Documents\HR-Dept\" -filter "youtube" -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Users\david.bowyer\Desktop\Testing\"

Comment: I suggest updating your original post to say you want to inspect the file contents. And, sorry, don't know what happened to the regex in my suggestion, it should be `$words -replace '\*'` - we need to escape the `*`

Comment: Also: 1. since you are checking the *contents*, `-filter` is not longer relevant so you need the `Select-String`. 2. You should have `-list` in your `Select-string` to stop searching for more matches the same file. You only need the file path for a copy. 3. When testing, **stop** piping to `Copy-Item` - try the search first to see if the results are OK. e.g. `(gci -r -file | Select-String "youtube" -list).path`  4. If you don't need to differentiate by each word for the file copies, you can search multiple terms in the regex: `Select-String "youtube|facebook|twitter" -list`

Comment: (Get-ChildItem C:\Users\David\Documents\Zoom\ -Recurse | Select-String "Bitlocker|nothing" -list).path                                                                                                               This works ONLY on txt files...  I have 2 .txt files - 2 .docx files and 2 .xlsx files.... one keyword in each...   it will not find the .docx and .xlsx

Comment: Keep it simple with your search queries while you're figuring it out - just try one string at a time. I tried the same search on a Server 2016 box and it didn't crack open the Office files either (Office is installed). Don't know all the differences between my Win 10 workstation and the server, but I noticed that `[System.Xml.Linq]` was being called by PS on Win10, but not 2016. The DLL exists in both places, but something's loading it in Win10 only. Don't know if it's relevant, but sorry, you'll need to look elsewhere now with parsing the content. It's been asked here before.

Comment: i found this, you can add    -Include *.docx,*.doc,*.txt,*.xls,*.pdf -Recurse                                 it wont search xlsx due to format is encrypted or something....   I cant figure out how to copy found files to new destination            
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27169043/powershell-search-matching-string-in-word-document